# How can I split this dataframe in multiple columns?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, split

I'm working with a .txt archive, when I use pd.read_csv the rows look like that:

|0 |
| -------- |
| 2452791.268864        1.000268                    0.000433          1 |
.
.
.

I want this this numbers in 4 different columns, something like that:

| Column A | Column B |
| -------- | -------- |
| 2452791.268864   | 1.000268 | ...
.
.
.

Note that the number of spaces between each number is different.

I'm so glad for your help!!!

I'm tried to use split functions but I don't get what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either set the `delim_whitespace` parameter of [**`pandas.read_csv`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to `True` :

```
df = pd.read_csv("your_text_file.txt", header=None, delim_whitespace=True)
```

Or use `"\s+"` (one space or more) as a separator :

```
df = pd.read_csv("your_text_file.txt", header=None, sep="\s+")
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df)

              0         1         2  3
0  2.452791e+06  1.000268  0.000433  1

print(len(df.columns))

4
```